# If we use querying with GORM will reduce the performance issue?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm new to Grails.
In our product we are using Grails framework with Hibernate. In that we are using SQL query to get a data from DB. My question is,

1. If we querying the data by **Querying with GORM** (dynamic query) will reduce the performance issue?
2. What is the use of dynamic query in GORM?

Any one please help me to find out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> If we querying the data by Querying with GORM (dynamic query) will
>   reduce the performance issue?

It is impossible to say without knowing how performance or not-performant what you have now is.  Using an ORM tool can add performance cost by adding layers of behavior and can also improve performance by imposing efficiencies in places where it would be difficult or impractical for the application to do so.  All you have said is that you are using SQL to get data and without knowing more about the data and how your system access it, it is impossible to say what the best solution for you is.

> What is the use of dynamic query in GORM?

Simplicity and expressiveness are both benefits of using dynamic queries.  In some case, performance would be a benefit.